# How to source ~/.bashrc when ssh send command to remote

Tags: ssh

In the machine 10.10.99.10, there is an ~/.bashrc who has the following line to set a variable.

```
var="hello"
```

When I use `ssh user@10.10.99.10:  echo ${var}`, ${var} is empty.
So I guess that the ~/.bashrc is not sourced before ssh's command is executed.

I try `ssh user@10.10.99.10: source ~/.bashrc; echo ${var}` but nothing changed.

How can I source the ~/.bashrc before ssh's command is executed?

Comment: `ssh user@10.10.99.10 'echo $var'` / `ssh user@10.10.99.10 '. ~/.bashrc; echo $var'`

Comment: without quoting, the local shell expands `${var}` before ssh sees it

Comment: Thx, I try without quoting, but still show nothing. I still think it does not source the ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 1):

My `~/.bashrc` contains this line:

```bash
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

I comment this line, and `source` works as expected.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I find the reason.
There are following lines in the head of `.bashrc`

```
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

I echo $- which is `hBc`, so it just returns.

I comment these lines and all works.